# CSS form with width and validation error message right of the form

Tags: asp.net, html, css, formatting

I have a simple html form.
This form has a specific width and margin auto so the form is in the middle of the screen.

```
form 
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 600px;
    width: 650px;
}
```

I validate if all textboxes are filled. I use asp:RequiredFieldValidator with an own css class

```
.ErrorMessage
{
    position:relative;
    left: 80px;
    width: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline;
}
```

But the error message are not shown right off the form because of the max width of the form. The error message will break to a second line. I can't use absolute position because the form is in the middle of the screen.

The problem is that the form has a border and i can't expand the max width.
This is a screenshot: http://suffball.de/form_error.png

How can I put the error message in right of the form? I need a solution without javascript.

Is this possible?

Thank You!

Comment: Can you post some sample markup?

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML for a short form?

Comment: did you tried **float: right;** in your css code?

Comment: this is a screenshot: http://suffball.de/form_error.png

Comment: How is its possible to keep error messages on the right if there is no space in the right. It will be good if you display error messages just below the input fields.

Comment: Yes this is possible, but i think it is hard to know which textbox is mean, over or under the error message. Is it possible to mark the textbox in red color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `.ErrorMessage` Css Class like below:

```
.ErrorMessage
{
    position:relative;
    left: 80px;
    width: 150px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display:inline;
    float: right;
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.